# Best way to highlight polygon on hover event with custom color in PIXI.js?

Tags: javascript, 2d, pixi.js

The simple way to highlight polygon:

```
var poly = ...;
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
graphics.drawPolygon(poly);
graphics.hitArea = poly;
graphics.interactive = true;
graphics.buttonMode = true;
graphics.mouseover = function () {
    graphics.alpha = 0.5;
};
graphics.mouseout = function () {
    graphics.alpha = 1;
};
```

But now it's not enough. I need to highlight polygon with another color.

Another way using closure:

```
graphics.mouseover = function (event) {
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.beginFill(hoverColor);
    graphics.drawPolygon(poly);
};
graphics.mouseout = function (event) {
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.beginFill(color);
    graphics.drawPolygon(poly);
};
```

But is there ways to do this avoiding call of `graphics.clear()` and polygon redrawing?

Comment: You could use tint. `graphics.tint = color;`

Comment: Karmacon, this is the answer